# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error in IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

My ASP.NET site is working well in VS 2015.

But I have published it to IIS Express in Window 7, displays the below error.
[image]

That is my IIS Express config.
[image]

What's my wrong?

Comment: Seems it can't read your web.config, check if you have BOM , try to remove it first. Or any other symbols in the begining of xml that shouldnt be here

Comment: I don't know what is BOM.
Could you tell me in detail?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Open web.config in editor that can show invisible chars. And make sure to save file as UTF8 no-BOM and with no extra chars in front ( like 0x0B, 0 etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you google your error, literally first result is [this support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055)

And the very first entry is:

> HResult code *0x8007000d*
>
> *Error message*:
> Server Error in Application "application name"
> Cause
> HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error
> HRESULT: 0x8007000d
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> *Cause*:
> This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config file or the Web.config file contains a malformed XML element.
>
> *Resolution*:
> Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config file or from the Web.config file.

So either in the very begining of your file you have some chars that should not be here , or you XML is just malformed.

Comment: I removed BOM but still the same. And my web.config have no malformed element. Here is what I tried.
My web.config have rewrite element.
When removing line by line and test, I found that is wrong.
So I installed rewrite_amd64.msi then fixed it.
Anyway thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try including runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" for the modules tag inside `<system.webServer>` tag of your web config file.

An example :

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

and if the issue still exists try logging the issue as mentioned in

https://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/working-past-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 0):

First, in VS you are using IIS Express, but the second screen shot shows IIS Manager, which means you are deploying the web app to IIS. IIS and IIS Express are different in far too many ways.

Second, the error page shows an error on line -1, which in most cases indicates a missing out-of-band module. Please go to http://iis.net to install them. Examples are, URL Rewrite module, ARR, and so on.

You can use Jexus Manager to verify as it can show more accurate error message than IIS Manager if a configuration error is detected.

https://www.jexusmanager.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the visual studio in Administrator mode. 
if not works, try to change the port of the iis express it may solve the issues.